# Why is the SHA256 regularly applied twice?

Tags: sha256

I have come across at least two times in bitcoin computations that the sha256 algorithm is applied twice - merkle root computation and address computation. Why is this?

Not sure of an appropriate tag - please edit.

Comment: Yes, didn't find that when I searched this question. Thanks

Comment: Yes stackexchange search is weird. I found this link in a reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/m1knq2/why_double_sha256_in_base58check_encoding_checksum/

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, I always feel a little embarrassed when my questions end up being duplicates. I don't entirely understand how a length extension attack could be employed with the merkle root calculation, but I'll spend some time researching the topic and post a more specific question that is not covered in the linked question if I can't figure it out.